# how to declare a class using the new keyword as property in a static class in c#

Tags: c#, class, static

I am currently building a `namespace` to handle complicated string actions. because I use the `this string` keyword, I must declare where the functions and properties are located as `static`. (the name of this class is "`StringExtension`") now I have another class named `StringExtensionSettings` and I use its `boolean properties` to determent what `functions` in the `class StringExtension` will be enabled. (for the user to choose what functions he wants to use and what not)
ex:

```cs
public class StringExtensionSettings
        {
            public bool DecryptString { get; set; } = true;
            public bool EncryptString { get; set; } = true;
            public bool RandomMix { get; set; } = true;
            public bool AddMidSubString { get; set; } = true;
        }
```

I don't want to warp the `string` in a `class` because it will make it complicated for the user. is there is any way to enable or disable `function` in a `static class` based on another class `properties`? and/or how to declare a `class` within a `static class`?

thank you in advance!

**Additional resources:**

the `StringExtension` class:

```cs
 static class StringExtension
    {
//this is what I'm trying to declare: gives an error
            public StringExtensionSettings StringSettings = new StringExtensionSettings();
            public static string AddMidSubString(this string Str, string MidSubString)
            {
            StringBuilder Result = new StringBuilder(Str);
            Result.Insert(Result.Length / 2, MidSubString);
            return Result.ToString();
            }
            public static string RandomMix(this string Str)
            {
            char[] array = Str.ToCharArray();
            Random rng = new Random();
            int n = array.Length;
            while (n > 1)
            {
                n--;
                int k = rng.Next(n + 1);
                var value = array[k];
                array[k] = array[n];
                array[n] = value;
            }
            return new string(array);
            }
// and more functions...
```

Comment: It's not possible `to enable or disable function in a static class based on another class properties` at compile time. You may add a checking into each function, and throw an exception if that function is disabled at runtime though

Comment: @Renat ok and how to declare a class within a static class?

Comment: Literally declare a class ( like `static class A{ public class B{public B(){}}}` )

Comment: Alternative 'solution'; define StringExtensionSettings as a static class. (Perhaps a Singleton, to avoid having multiple/ duplicate StringExtensionSettings objects).

Comment: @Odrai what is a 'Singleton'?

Comment: @Odrai but if I will make the class static then I will not be able to declare variables inside that class

Comment: @avivgood3 Please have a look at my answer. If you have any further questions or need more information, please feel free to ask. In case a Singleton doesn't meet the requirements/ suits your needs, perhaps you will need to pass a StringExtensionSettings object everytime you call a method of the StringExtension class.

Comment: So are the values in `StringExtensionSettings` supposed to prevent/allow access to methods within `StringExtension` at compile time? Or just throw some sort of exception if somebody tries using a specific method at runtime?

Comment: @devNull my vision is that will be in compile-time... but I don't think it is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Follow-up of my comment in the OP*

Within a [Singleton](https://www.dotnetperls.com/singleton) (class), you are still able/ allowed to define fields.

> The singleton design pattern is an interface. It is a popular class
>   type for programs. It allows a class to enforce that it is only
>   allocated (read -> created) once.

```
public sealed class StringExtensionSettings
{
    private StringExtensionSettings()
    {
    }

    private static StringExtensionSettings instance = null;
    public static StringExtensionSettings Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = new StringExtensionSettings();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }

    public bool DecryptString { get; set; } = true;
    public bool EncryptString { get; set; } = true;
    public bool RandomMix { get; set; } = true;
    public bool AddMidSubString { get; set; } = true;
}
```

***Usage:***

Single Field call

```
StringExtensionSettings.Instance.AddMidSubString
```

Implementation

```
public static string AddMidSubString(this string Str, string MidSubString)
{
    if (StringExtensionSettings.Instance.AddMidSubString)
    {
        StringBuilder Result = new StringBuilder(Str);
        Result.Insert(Result.Length / 2, MidSubString);
        return Result.ToString();
    }
    throw new Exception($"Not allowed to call {nameof(AddMidSubString)}");
}
```

Summarized; calling `StringExtensionSettings.Instance`creates a new instance of StringExtensionSettings, only (once!), when the private field `instance` of `StringExtensionSettings` is null.

Comment: but when I try ```StringExtensionSettings SES = new StringExtensionSettings();``` it still gives me the same error that it cannot declare in a static class